# Finding all rational (closed and connected) subgroups of $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb R)$ with respect to $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb Z)$

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, homogeneous-spaces

A subgroup $H$ of $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb R)$ is called *rational* w.r.t. the lattice $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb Z)$ if $H \cap \text{SL}(2,\mathbb Z)$ is a lattice in $H$ (namely the quotient homogeneous space has a probability Haar measure).

I would like to find all rational, closed and connected subgroups of $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb R)$ with respect to $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb Z)$, but I don't know how hard this question is and where to start.

Comment: What are you studying? What text is this drawn from, if any? If not, how did the question arise? What kind of approaches (to similar problems) are you familiar with? What kind of answer are you looking for? Basic approach, hint, explanation, something else? Is this question something you think you should be able to answer? Why or why not?

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by "find". For instance, your list will include the real Zariski closure of every infinite cyclic subgroup of $SL(2,Z)$, plus some compact subgroups (easily listed, all conjugate to three particular compact subgroups) and $SL(2,R)$ itself. Do you find this satisfactory?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks. Now I see how hard this is.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be listed in a reasonable way.

These are:

1. the trivial group $\{1\}$,
2. the whole group $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{R})$,
3. the $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{R})$-conjugates of the 1-dimensional compact group $\mathrm{SO}_2(\mathbf{R})$,
4. various non-compact 1-dimensional subgroups, namely: for each $n\ge 2$, the unit component $H'_n$ of the centralizer $H_n$ in $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{R})$ of the matrix $M_n=\begin{pmatrix}0 & -1\\ 1& n\end{pmatrix}$, and its $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{Q})$-conjugates. (Unit component is actually the unique subgroup of index $2$, except for $n=2$ in which case it has index $1$.)

These subgroups indeed satisfy the condition: indeed for conjugates of $H_n$ one gets the real points of a 1-dimensional $\mathbf{Q}$-anisotropic torus and hence integral matrices form a lattice therein, using Borel-HarishChandra (or a direct argument).

Conversely, let $L$ be a connected closed subgroup with the given condition. If its dimension is $0$ or $3$ we are done. If its dimension is $2$, then $L$ is conjugate to the group of upper triangular matrices with positive diagonal and det 1, which is not unimodular, and hence has no lattice, so this is excluded. Hence $L$ has dimension $1$. If $L$ is compact, it is a real conjugate of $\mathrm{SO}_2(\mathbf{R})$.

Now assume that $L$ is 1-dimensional and non-compact. It contains an integral matrix of determinant 1 and infinite order, hence of trace $\neq 0,\pm 1$; up to squaring we can suppose its trace is $n\ge 2$. Hence it is conjugate to $M_n$, and since then the centralizer of $M_n$ is 1-dimensional, we are done.

**Remark:** if we classify the subgroups $H_n$ (or equivalently $H'_n$) up to $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{Q})$-conjugacy, then we have to identify some values of $n$. Namely, $H_n$ and $H_m$ are $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{Q})$-conjugate iff $M_n,M_m$ have positive powers with the same trace. So for a "unique" classification, we need to discard $n\ge 3$ when there exist $m\ge 3$ and $k\ge 2$ such that $\mathrm{Tr}(M_m^k)=n$.

This discards the following set $X$ of values: 7, 14, 18, 23, 34, 47, 52, 62, 79, 98, 110, 119, 123, 142, 167, 194, 198, 223, 254, 287... (for instance, $7=\mathrm{Tr}(M_3^2)$, $14=\mathrm{Tr}(M_4^2)$, $18=\mathrm{Tr}(M_3^3)$...) these seem to coincide with the set of values $\ge 7$ of the sequence [OEIS/A298878](https://oeis.org/A298878). The $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{Q})$-conjugacy classes of subgroups $H_n$ are thus indexed by $n\in\mathbf{N}_{\ge 2}\smallsetminus X$.

**Remark 2** I'm not sure that "rational" is an adequate terminology: indeed it usually means that the subgroup is definable by equations with rational coefficients, and includes, for instance, the upper triangular group or the diagonal group. For rational connected subgroups $H\subset\mathrm{GL}_n$ (in this genuine sense), whether the integral matrices form a lattice is given by the Borel-Harish-Chandra criterion, namely iff $H$ has no nontrivial rational character (i.e. no nontrivial $\mathbf{Q}$-defined homomorphism into $\mathrm{GL}_1$).